# Glossaries: Creating a page link to the entry without printing its name

Tags: glossaries

Is there a way to just add a reference to something without displaying the name of the glossary item?
Such as:

"Foo exists in the glossary.\gls{foo}"

becoming

"Foo exists in the glossary."

instead of

"Foo exists in the glossary.foo"

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that shows your problem and that we can compile, otherwise how do you expect us to (wrongly) guess what you might have done?

Comment: You say `...glossary.\gls{foo}` giving "..,. glossary.foo" but you don't want the "foo". So why the `\gls{foo}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome, in the future please post a MWE ([please consult this link so you know how to write one in the future](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)), I know yours is more of a question but it really helps us help you. A possible solution is using the "first" key in `\newglossaryentry`, which is the text and/or symbols you wish to be included the first time you use the entry with `\gls`:

[image]

Code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{foo}
    {%
    name={foo},
    description={description of foo that appears in glossary},
    first={Foo exists in the glossary},
    }
    
\makeglossary

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\gls{foo}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The `arara` commands are the method I use to compile documents, it means you do not have to manually run `pdflatex`, `makeglossaries`, `pdflatex`, have a look at it if you're interested but you can delete the `arara` commands if you wish. Hope this helps.

Edit: This is the template I use so I remember which glossary entries I need and which to use in documents if you have never seen all the entries before:

```
%\newglossaryentry{in-text \gls name}
%   {%
%   name={name that appears in glossary},
%   description={description that appears in glossary},
%   text={in-text where singular form required, if not defined uses name}
%   first={first time used with singular form, if not defined uses text},
%   plural={plural form, if not defined adds s to text value},
%   firstplural={first time plural used},
%   symbols={adds a symbol if needed},
%   sort={how to sort entry},
%   type={glossary name that this entry belongs to},
%   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and thoughtful answer. Setting text to be empty in the glossary entry solved my problem.